# Antlr4.6 BaseVisitor and Visitor errors : Visitor (Interface) is abstract; cannot be instantiated BaseVisitor (Class) & super() error

Tags: java, interface, antlr, visitor-pattern

I am trying to make antrl4 4.6. work but I get 4 errors which are advanced and I can't get through them. Can anyone help me please? Maybe needs anonymous class.

Also the super() error, I have it in correct position but it deny to work.

```
Yoco.java:34: error: YocoVisitor is abstract; cannot be instantiated
        YocoVisitor eval = new YocoVisitor(dictInt, dictProcD);
                           ^ YocoBaseVisitor.java:6: error: YocoBaseVisitor is not abstract and does not override abstract method visitR(RContext) in YocoVisitor public class YocoBaseVisitor extends AbstractParseTreeVisitor<Integer> implements YocoVisitor<Integer> {
        ^ YocoBaseVisitor.java:12: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override public Integer visitR(HashMap<String, Integer> _dictInt, HashMap<String, YocoParser.ProcDefContext> _dictProcD) {
        ^ YocoBaseVisitor.java:13: error: call to super must be first statement in constructor
>                 super();
                    ^ 4 errors

YocoBaseVisitor.java:


// Generated from Yoco.g4 by ANTLR 4.6
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeVisitor;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class YocoBaseVisitor extends AbstractParseTreeVisitor<Integer> implements YocoVisitor<Integer> {
    HashMap<String, Integer> dictInt = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    HashMap<String, YocoParser.ProcDefContext> dictProcD = new HashMap<String, YocoParser.ProcDefContext>();
    @Override public Integer visitR(HashMap<String, Integer> _dictInt, HashMap<String, YocoParser.ProcDefContext> _dictProcD) { 
        super();
        dictInt = _dictInt;
        dictProcD = _dictProcD;
    }
}

YocoVisitor.java:
{

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeVisitor;
public interface YocoVisitor<Integer> extends ParseTreeVisitor<Integer> {
}


Yoco.java:

public class Yoco {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputFile = null; 
        if(args.length > 0)
        inputFile = args[0];
        InputStream is = System.in;
        if (inputFile != null)
        is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(is);
        YocoLexer lexer = new YocoLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        YocoParser parser = new YocoParser(tokens);

        ParseTree tree = parser.r();
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));

    // Hash table for integer variables.
    HashMap<String, Integer> dictInt = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    // Hash table for procedure expressions with parameters.
    HashMap<String, YocoParser.ProcDefContext> dictProcD = new HashMap<String, YocoParser.ProcDefContext>();

    YocoVisitor eval = new YocoVisitor(dictInt, dictProcD);
    System.out.println();
    eval.visit(tree);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 1 ->  YocoVisitor is interface , and interface cannot be instantiated. 
Instead of
 YocoVisitor eval = new YocoVisitor(dictInt, dictProcD);
One has to write and create corresponding constructor in YocoBaseVisitor 
YocoVisitor eval = new YocoBaseVisitor (dictInt, dictProcD);

Error 2 -> 
super () can only be called in constructor of class as first line. You have called in method.

Error 3 -> method visitR is overriden correctly check syntax.

Hopefully shoud solve all problem.